# Erasing MySQL db when running on JBoss 4.2.3

Tags: mysql, jboss, ejb-3.0

I use MySql with MySql Workbench and JBoss 4.2.3. When the JBoss server is loaded or stopped  the entire database fully erased. But if I insert the data after the server is loaded, everything works fine... Do you have any ideas why JBoss have such strange behavior?

Answer (score 2):

it can be because of the setting of your persistance like create-drop after deployment and when Jboss starts it deploys your app and drop database and create new